# JAVASCRIPT - Telegraf | How can I add a cooldown to this action?

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, telegraf

I've been trying to add a cooldown to this part of my code for its too spammable to the point where I had to ban certain ppl from using it. So I've researched into cooldowns, trying different methods with no avail so I want to ask here if anyone has some hints or possible solutions to this. Thanks in advance.

````js
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const Telegram = require('telegraf/telegram')
const bot = new Telegraf('******')

bot.hears(['oe', 'Oe', 'OE'], (ctx) => {
    if (ctx.message.reply_to_message && ctx.message.reply_to_message.from.username != 'a username' && ctx.from.id != '****') {   // Check if you're replying and if you're someone banned to use this command

        var a = ctx.message.reply_to_message.from.username
        ctx.reply('¿@ este usuario?', {
            reply_markup: {
                inline_keyboard: [
                    [{ text: "Si", callback_data: "AD" }, { text: "Sin't", callback_data: "ADNT" }]
                ]
            }
        })
        bot.action('AD', (ctx) => {
            ctx.deleteMessage()
            ctx.reply('@' + a + ' oe')
            ctx.replyWithSticker('CAACAgEAAxkBAAOsX9WKywuspdVls5VSf9xV6ZLHrqAAAg8AA5390hUNDOUjryN26R4E')
        })
        bot.action('ADNT', (ctx) => {
            ctx.deleteMessage()
        })

    } else {
        console.log('No reply_to_message found! or the user is banned from doing this command')
    }
})/**/ ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Timestamps

[Date.now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) will give you a timestamp in milliseconds. When the bot triggers, see if it has a timestamp. If it does, get a current timestamp and get the difference between timestamps. If it's under your threshold (say 5 seconds (5000ms)), skip replying. If it's over your threshold, update your saved timestamp with your current timestamp and have the bot reply.

### Complete Guess

I'm not able to run the code and I'm not certain how it works, but my guess would be something along these lines

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const Telegram = require('telegraf/telegram')
const bot = new Telegraf('******')

let timestamp;

bot.hears(['oe', 'Oe', 'OE'], (ctx) => {

    const rightNow = Date.now();
    if(timestamp) {
        // we have a timestamp from the last time we triggered
        // so let's see if we've waited long enough...

        const difference = rightNow - timestamp;
        if(difference >= (5 * 1000) {
            // enough time has elapsed, go ahead and do our thing
            // but first, reset the timestamp for next time
            timestamp = rightNow;
        } else {
             // nope, haven't waited long enough, abort, abort!
             return;
        }
    } else {
        // no timestamp available so this must be the first time
        timestamp = rightNow;
    }

    if (ctx.message.reply_to_message && ctx.message.reply_to_message.from.username != 'a username' && ctx.from.id != '****') {   // Check if you're replying and if you're someone banned to use this command

        var a = ctx.message.reply_to_message.from.username
        ctx.reply('¿@ este usuario?', {
            reply_markup: {
                inline_keyboard: [
                    [{ text: "Si", callback_data: "AD" }, { text: "Sin't", callback_data: "ADNT" }]
                ]
            }
        })
        bot.action('AD', (ctx) => {
            ctx.deleteMessage()
            ctx.reply('@' + a + ' oe')
            ctx.replyWithSticker('CAACAgEAAxkBAAOsX9WKywuspdVls5VSf9xV6ZLHrqAAAg8AA5390hUNDOUjryN26R4E')
        })
        bot.action('ADNT', (ctx) => {
            ctx.deleteMessage()
        })

    } else {
        console.log('No reply_to_message found! or the user is banned from doing this command')
    }
})/**/
```